Use gcloud CLI to modify runtime service account of a Cloud Function
I have multiple Cloud Functions V2 running on GCP.
On the console, I can modify the runtime service account of it, the function will restart and be up and running again with the new service account.
I'm trying to do a similar operation using gcloud CLI.
I know you can select a service account with --service-account when using gcloud functions deploy but I'm looking to do a similar operation that I'm doing manually in the console.
--> Being able to change the service account without having the source code around or using gcloud functions deploy.
Is it possible in the gcloud cli ?
Thank you

It's not possible to change only the runtime SA on a Cloud Functions. In the Cloud Functions model, it's a new revision, so you must take your code, package it in a new container and redeploy it with the new service account.
The UI does it for you in a convenient way. With CLI, you must do it by yourselves. If you use Infra As Code, like terraform, it's also easier to achieve (change the terraform config, apply the new config and it's done)
